# Rotating sprite in java LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

Have an asset class for the sprite which defines a texture, then the sprite as that texture sheet, with coordinates for the sheet. this is the sprite i am trying to rotate.
I have been given the advice to rotate it using Sprite Batch (it rotates to my touch input:

```
batch.draw(TextureRegion region,
                 float x,
                 float y,
                 float originX,
                 float originY,
                 float width,
                 float height,
                 float scaleX,
                 float scaleY,
                 float rotation)
```

and i get the error:

The method `draw(Texture, float, float, int, int, int, int)` in the type SpriteBatch is not applicable for the arguments `(Sprite, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float)`

Is there a sort of way to cast a sprite to a texture or a better way to rotate it it just isn't working please help!

Comment: you're getting this problem because you're trying to pass in ints to a function that is expecting floats. Try casting all the ints to floats when you call the function.

Comment: @clearlyspam23 i tries this 'game.batch.draw(FarmerAsset.upFarmer1, farmerX, farmerY, (float)85, (float)85, (float)170, (float)170, (float)1, (float)angleDegrees);
  '                          but i still get the same error is it not to do with using sprite oppesed to texture?

Comment: according to the [SpriteBatch docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-), there should be an overload that takes a TextureRegion, and according to the [Sprite docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html), Sprites should be TextureRegions, so that should work. It looks to me like you might be missing a parameter on your function call (you have scaleX but no scaleY)

Comment: @clearlyspam23 my friend thank u, u r a genius i'll happily accep your answer if u would like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the **rotate(float degrees)** .
Sets the sprite's rotation in degrees relative to the current rotation.

you must use the rotate(float degrees) in render method of your class.

as given in  [Sprite Class documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html)